# How to create a chat room in MSE?

Tags: support, chat

I have seen some of the users have created their chat rooms. I, too, wanted to create my own chat room. So, how can I create, please somebody help me?

Comment: A (rather brief) description can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms).

Answer (score 3):

Go to the [following URL](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com):

Click on "**Create a new room**" (Note that this option will only pop up for users with over 100 reputation).

Then, a window like this should pop up:
[image]
Be sure that the "**Related Site**" is "**Mathematics**" and choose a Room Name. You may configure the options to your preference, and then click on "**create new room**".

Note that all conversations are public, regardless of the options you choose.